# use of undeclared identifier 'NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption'

Tags: ios5, core-data-migration, uimanageddocument

How come I get this error when I'm declaring the code statement below?

> use of undeclared identifier 'NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption'

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

What am I missing in order to get this to recognize my NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption constant?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: useful question. I fell into the same mistake today. ugh. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption is declared in NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.h.  Are you sure that that is included or forwarded wherever you're building that dictionary (like by including CoreData.h)?

Comment: :) that was exactly what I was missing #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>